# getderivedstate function makes state uneditable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

i am using reactjs with meteor
currently i have a form which is the user info update, i load the information like email and phone number into the form automatically using the getderivedstatefromprops function, but the problem is the textfields are now non editable.
i am passing the state as value to the textfields
how to fix this problem?

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState){
    return({
        email: nextProps.user && nextProps.user.hasOwnProperty("emails") ? nextProps.user.emails[0].address : prevState.email,
        password: prevState.password,
        name: nextProps.user && nextProps.user.hasOwnProperty("name") ? nextProps.user.name : prevState.name,
        mobileNumber: nextProps.user && nextProps.user.hasOwnProperty("mobileNumber") ? nextProps.user.mobileNumber : prevState.mobileNumber,
        address: nextProps.user && nextProps.user.hasOwnProperty("address") ? nextProps.user.address.text : prevState.address
    });
}

 <TextField hintText="Tu Email" onChange={this.handleInputChange}  style={{fontFamily:'Montserrat', textAlign: 'center'}}
                  name='email' value={this.state.email} type="email"
                  errorText={this.state.emailError} hintStyle={{ width:'100%', textAlign: 'center' }}
                  inputStyle={{ textAlign: 'center' }}/>
                  <div style={{paddingTop:'30px'}}></div>
                  <p>Nombre</p>
                  <TextField hintText="Tu nombre" onChange={this.handleInputChange} style={{fontFamily:'Montserrat'}} name='name' value={this.state.name}
                  errorText={this.state.nameError} hintStyle={{ width:'100%', textAlign: 'center' }}
                  inputStyle={{ textAlign: 'center' }}/>
                  <div style={{paddingTop:'30px'}}></div>
                  <p>Número de WhatsApp</p>
                  <TextField hintText="Tu número de WhatsApp" onChange={this.handleInputChange} style={{fontFamily:'Montserrat'}}
                  name='mobileNumber' value={this.state.mobileNumber} type='tel'
                  errorText={this.state.numberError} hintStyle={{ width:'100%', textAlign: 'center' }}
                  inputStyle={{ textAlign: 'center' }}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the input fields have not become non-editable. The **getDerivedStateFromProps** lifecycle is called, everytime a prop or state is changed.

So, whenever any change is made to the **Inputfield**, the props or state get changed and the **getDerivedStateFromProps** lifecycle is called again. Hence, resetting the **Textfields** to the initial values.

Perform a conditional check within getDerivedStateFromProps, such that the initial values are set only when the lifecycle is called for the first time.

For example, try something like:

```
//  set initialCount to 0 in constructor 
constructor () {
    this.state = { initialCount: 0 };
}


static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState){
    if (prevState.initialCount === 0) {
        return({
        initialCount: prevState.initialCount + 1,
        email: nextProps.user && 
           nextProps.user.hasOwnProperty("emails") ? 
           nextProps.user.emails[0].address : prevState.email,
           password: prevState.password,
           name: nextProps.user && 
           nextProps.user.hasOwnProperty("name") ? nextProps.user.name 
           : prevState.name,
           mobileNumber: nextProps.user && 
           nextProps.user.hasOwnProperty("mobileNumber") ? 
           nextProps.user.mobileNumber : prevState.mobileNumber,
           address: nextProps.user && 
           nextProps.user.hasOwnProperty("address") ? 
           nextProps.user.address.text : prevState.address
       });
    }
}
```

Comment: It is prevState.initialCount, I have updated the code

Comment: works but if i press refresh on the page the textfields will load with blank values